# Error when comparing time difference with amount of days in month

Tags: c#, timespan

I am subtracting two dates and then comparing the day difference to how many days are within one month but it is crashing. Here is the code:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Subtract(File.GetLastWriteTime(TestWorkbook(worksheets[i].Path) + ".xlsx").Date)) < DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month))
```

and the error I am receiving is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'

Why is this happening?

Comment: TimeSpan doesn't implement `IConvertible`, which is what `Convert.ToInt32(...)` expects.

Comment: @Amy so what do I need to convert it to in order to compare the numbers?

Comment: It's not convertible to a number.  Just speaking conceptually, what does it mean for a timespan to be converted to a number?  A timespan has numerous properties for getting lengths of time out, such as `TotalMilliseconds` or `Days`, which give you the number of milliseconds or days represented by the timespan, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if i understand what you are trying to do i removed the Convert.ToInt32 and added .Days. This should work. So try:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(File.GetLastWriteTime(TestWorkbook(worksheets[i].Path) + ".xlsx").Date).Days < DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month))
    //Do whatever
```